# Mouse events not handled within QQuickItem inheritor

Tags: qt, qtquick2, scenegraph

I want to write simple Qt Quick app with draggable QQuickItems. The items are well draggeble because of embedded MouseArea in the items. But a problem is that mouse events are not fired into C++ code in virtual overloaded functions. How to solve this problem or maybe there are some examples that I didn't find?

The QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import SimpleMaterial 1.0

Rectangle {
width: 320
height: 480
color: "black"

    SimpleMaterialItem {
        width: parent.width;
        height: parent.height / 3;
        color: "steelblue"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            width: 64
            height: 64

            drag.target: parent
            drag.axis: Drag.XandYAxis
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ class:

```
class Item : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
public:
    Item()
    {
        setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
        setFlag(ItemAcceptsDrops, true);
        setFlag(ItemAcceptsInputMethod, true);
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
    {
        qDebug("Press");  // NOT CALLED!
    }

public:
    QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *node, UpdatePaintNodeData *)
    {
    ...
    }
};
```

Comment: "mouse events are not caused in C++"? You mean something like: "The events are not fired?"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: yes, I rephrased the sentence

Comment: Tried `onPressed: console.log("Clicked")` ? or really needs to be "mousePressEvent"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MouseArea` handles mouse event it doesn't pass event to its parent.

You need:

```
onPressed: {
    mouse.accepted = false;
}
```

in mouse area to let the `SimpleMaterialItem` handle `onPressed` event.